# переделать пример на язык c++

Tags: c++

[image: как записать пример с этой картинки на язык c++?]

как записать пример с этой картинки на язык c++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
    
int main(){
    double y = 0;
    double a = 3;
    double b = 5;
    
    y = cbrt(a+b);
   
    return 0;
}
```

> y =
> 2